# find is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to understand why I'm getting this error. All I want to do is check if the array has an item with the class of 'active'. Using `Find` seems correct as it only needs to return 1 value. Here is my code:

```
const tabWrapper = document.querySelector('.nav-tabs');
const tabs = tabWrapper.getElementsByTagName('li');
const indicator = document.querySelector('.slider-indicator');
const tabWidth = tabWrapper.offsetWidth;
let startPos = tabWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().left;

console.log(tabs);

function checkActive(item) {
    console.log(item.classList.contains('active'));
}

tabs.find(checkActive);
```

Comment: well find is not a DOM HTML Collection method.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote this question... it's well asked, problem may not be so obvious for a rookie in Javascript.

Comment: A basic google search would reveal that `find` is an array method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: DOM query methods don't return an array, but an array like object. You'll need to convert them to an array first. Try `const tabs = Array.from(tabWrapper.getElementsByTagName('li'));`

Comment: @jmargolisvt it's not obvious that `getElementsByTagName`  doesn't return an array though

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's not very obvious that a nodelist is different from an array at first glance.

Comment: You might be better off with querySelector or querySelectorAll. `var activeLI = document.querySelector("li.active");`

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByTagName()` returns a **["live"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** node list, which is an **["array-like"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)** object, but not an actual array (it doesn't inherit from Array.prototype). As such, it won't implement all the methods that a real array does.

If you want to use the elements within that node list in an array structure, you must convert that node list into an actual array, which is done like this:

```
const tabs = Array.prototype.slice.call(tabWrapper.getElementsByTagName('li'));
```

Now, back to the "live" node list concept...A live node list is one that updates its contents upon each access of the variable referencing it. This means that 
 (in your case) every single time you use `tabs` in your code, the entire document is re-scanned for all `li` elements. There are only a few use cases for needing one and if you don't, you can possibly improve the performance of your code substantially by not using one. **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** is a more modern DOM API that returns a static node list, which is generally preferred.

```
const tabs = Array.prototype.slice.call(tabWrapper.querySelectorAlll('li'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with querySelector or querySelectorAll.

```
const activeLI = document.querySelector("li.active");
const activeLIs = document.querySelectorAll("li.active");
```

That will return which will give you the li element(s) with the active class. If you want to use Array methods, you need to convert the collection into an array.

```
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
const liArray = Array.from(lis);
console.log(liArray.find) // shows you now have a find method
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the NodeList into an array.

Your code to select the `<li>` elements should be fine, I changed it so I could use minimal HTML in the example.

```js
const tabs = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

console.log(tabs);

function checkActive(item) {
    return item.classList.contains('active');
}

console.log("Found anything: " + Boolean(Array.from(tabs).find(checkActive)));
```

```html
<li class="active">foo</li>
<li class="randomClass">bar</li>
```